# when clicking on checkbox it shows false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="checked" @click='toggle'>
 {{checked}}
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checked: false,
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
    console.log(this.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

When clicking a checkbox the console value is shown as false but in the view it is printed as true. Why is it tha the value are different in console and the view?

here is a link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbx6tf7n/). Please check console value and view value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Console Logs it before the actual change happened, for example if you change the `console.log()` into an `alert()` you can clearly see the timing order and which action is performed first.

Edit: You could set a watcher on the checked so whenever the value actually changed you perform an action

```
watch: {
    checked: function (val) {
       console.log(val)
    },
```

Comment: even if i dont console.log it , it will show me the opposite value. I need to access it in my method.

Comment: @Raaz Check out my Edit.

Comment: instead of using the watcher, I changed `@click` to `@change` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a delay in the execution as Badgy mentioned above. The issue is that you try to combine `v-model` and `@click`. In this case I would suggest to write a custom version of `v-model` that gives you more control.

In reality, `<input v-model="checked" />` is just a simpler form of `<input :value="checked" @input="checked= $event.target.value">` Therefore, you can do this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" :value="checked" @click='toggle'>
```

And toggle the value like this

```
toggle: function(){
  this.checked = !this.checked;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle of the result https://jsfiddle.net/dan_elision/7fx1kocp/. The advantage of this approach is that you have more control and you do not need to use watchers, which is a good habit to save only for expensive operations (see [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)).